# Issue generating firebase refresh token via firebase_app_distribution plugin for fastlane

Tags: fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I am having an issue with generating a firebase refresh token, wondering if anybody here has any suggestions.

I am using fastlane on a project, along with the firebase_app_distribution plugin.  I've generated firebase refresh tokens multiple times recently without any issue using this plugin.  The command I've used is:

`bundle exec fastlane run firebase_app_distribution_login`

That is well documented elsewhere.  That command gives you a link to open in your browser.  In the past, when I've done this, I was able to open that link without any issues.  However, now I'm getting an error from Google when I try to open the page:

[image]

I've updated to the latest versions of fastlane and of the plugin.

Anybody have any idea what is causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured I'd post an answer in case anybody else runs into this.  While I have not been able to get the fastlane firebase plugin to generate a new refresh token, I was able to do it with the firebase CLI.  I did have to update to the latest version of the CLI.  Just use "firebase login:ci" to generate a token.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who is experiencing this problem - *fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution* has released version **v0.3.4** 20 hours ago. Update your plugin to be able to publish through *fastlane* again.

`fastlane update_plugins`